# Used chown for /var/lib/mysql to change owner from root, now getting Error 1049 (42000) in mysql

Tags: mysql, permissions, root, ownership, chown

With Ubuntu, I previously created a mysql database using the following code in the terminal:

```
$ my sql -u root -p
```

Then within mysql:

```
CREATE DATABASE securities_master;
```

I was trying to use file explorer to view the contents related to this database. But because I did not have permissions to open the folder /var/lib/mysql I wanted to change the permissions on this folder. I did some searching on stackoverflow, and without fully understanding what I was doing, I used something like the following (my username being wei):

```
sudo chown -R root:wei /var/lib/mysql
```

OR (unfortunately I had since closed terminal window so not sure exactly what I typed)

```
sudo chown -R wei:wei /var/lib/mysql
```

OR

```
sudo chown -R wei /var/lib/mysql
```

This allowed me to view inside the directory and see my files, so I thought I was making progress. However, once I had done this I realized that when I tried to USE the database in mysql:

```
USE securities_database;
```

I was getting an error message like:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'securities_master'
```

I believe this is related to my use of chown earlier. Upon looking into this with further stackoverflow searches, I'm now under the impression I shouldn't be willy nilly taking away root ownership of some files from root as "bad things can happen". I've tried to restore root ownership with:

```
sudo chown -R root /var/lib/mysql
```

AND/OR:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /var/lib/mysql
```

But unfortunately I seem to still get the same error message.

I apologize if my question seems so basic, or such a rookie error, total newbie to Ubuntu, Linux and mysql here. Thanks.

Comment: `SHOW databases;` lists your created database?

Comment: Came up with an error as I had the incorrect ownership, but once I fixed it as per @Barmar 's suggestion, it did indeed show the database, thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The normal ownership of everything in `/var/lib/mysql` is `mysql:mysql`. So you should be able to fix it with:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: That 3 line comment solved my problem in 10 seconds after I had spent 4 hours trying to solve it myself prior to that. I wish I could upvote (but have reputation less than 15), and if you lived closer to me I would buy you a beer. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know Windows system administration.

Comment: How did you accidentally change the ownership in the first place? You should be able to change it back with the same command.

Comment: i didnt - basically mysql server is attacked with ransom
i am following this article to recvover db
https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-tablespace-is-missing-for-table/
stuck on step 4

Comment: You could try searching for this information in the [MySQL Windows Installation documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html) I looked at a few pages and didn't see anything about ownership.